# socket php hangs on fgets (telegram-cli)

Tags: php, linux, sockets, terminal, telegram

here is my code

```
<?php
$s=stream_socket_client ('unix:///tmp//mmd.sck');
set_time_limit(0);
$fg= fgets($s);
echo $fg
?>
```

i made a Unix socket (telegram cli) and want to use it untill get the output line of the Terminal.
But the page does not load, and don't give me no results .

https://github.com/vysheng/tg/wiki/Telegram-CLI-Arguments
This page reminds me to make unix socket and I don't know how the socket working ...